# Bootstrap carousel error, only active image appears

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so, I was following this tutorial on YT, and everything is fine so far, except carousel is showing only the active image, and wont switch to others. I checked the code multiple times, everything is on place, but it just won't work. Please answer if you know what's wrong, I'll appreciate it so much! :)

Here is the code:

```
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="img/mountains.png">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Lorem Ipsum</button>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- Kraj active slajdera -->
    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/snow.png">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/red.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Strelice Pocetak -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div> <!--Kraj slajdera -->
```

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 1):

From you example if you have added the bootstrap assest and jquery , and the `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">` every thing should work fine :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://www.moroccoworldnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/moroccan-Sahara.jpg">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Lorem Ipsum</button>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- Kraj active slajdera -->
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.dempos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Home-Company-Dempo-Travels.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://www.moroccoworldnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/moroccan-Sahara.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Strelice Pocetak -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```